# XCode/Cocoa + Quartz Composer + Interface Builder woes

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder, quartz-composer

So, I can't seem to get this (I thought rather simple) Cocoa app working properly.  I have a Quartz Composer patch which writes text files based on GUI input, then recalls the text files and displays them on a second display (ie projector.)  Everything works as expected from inside QC.  That's not (as far as I can tell) the problem.

I managed to build the UI in Interface Builder, and set up the bindings for text boxes and a submit button.  There are two windows, a GUI and a QCView window.  When I simulate it in Cocoa Simulator, both windows show up, the QC view plays the composition, and the text boxes/buttons DO talk to the QC patch (tested it.)  However, for whatever reason, the patch doesn't make new text files when pressing the submit button.  (I am hoping this is just weirdness with the simulator, and that it will work when I can get the .app working.)

In the XCode project, I added the IB UI and the Quartz framework (yes, I made sure - I was following [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/QuartzComposer/qc_play_ib/qc_play_ib.html) tutorial) It compiles and runs successfully, with no errors in the console, but there is (inexplicably) no QCView window to be found.  Also, the GUI window shows up fine, but just like the simulator, if I fill in the text boxes and press submit, no text files are written.  It seems like the Cocoa app isn't even loading the QC patch (even in the background.)

Erm.  Halp?  I have no idea where to even start.  I'm not a big code person, just patching and such, so if the solution requires any hard code please be gentle, hahaha.

Answer (score 0):

Are you showing the QCView window explicitly?

If not, do you have its “visible on launch” checkbox checked?

Comment: Yes, visible on launch is checked... how would I check to make sure it's being shown explicitly?

Comment: capsaicin: I originally asked the question in the active voice; that is important. Are *you* showing it explicitly? If the program wasn't originally yours or is old enough that you might have forgotten some of it, do a project-wide find (⇧⌘F) for selectors such as `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, `orderFront:`, `orderBack:`, and NSWindowController's `showWindow:`.